# Add an item to a checkbox in a content type

Tags: 7

I started working with drupal recently and I have been assigned many small tasks. I would like to know how I can add an item to the following checkbox, I can't understand how:
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Click on "field settings" in the top right hand corner of that screen. That's where storage specific options are held.

If you can edit the options there then it's a simple text list. But it may be that field is referencing a taxonomy term or content/entity but that tab will lead you in the right direction to add an item

Answer (score 1):

Once a field is created, you can still change its settings clicking on the *Field settings* tab you see in the screenshot you took.

> [image: screenshot]

As you notice, the warning tell you the settings cannot be longer changed, as there is already a node containing data for that field. That doesn't mean you cannot change anything for that field. For example, I was able to add a new value to the list, which is what you want to do.

> [image: screenshot]

What you cannot do is removing values that are used. In that case, you get an error message, similarly to what happened to me when I tried to remove the default value (*frontpage|Front page*), which was used from the test node I created.
The message is clear: *Allowed values list: some values are being removed while currently in use.*

> [image: screenshot]